# OpenOffice API: URL seems to be an unsupported one

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-api

I get this exception for a seemingly valid URL:

```
document = componentLoader.loadComponentFromURL(templateURL, "_blank", FrameSearchFlag.CREATE, new PropertyValue[0]);
```

Called with `templateURL` being:

```
file:///var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/convert/WEB-INF/template.odp
```

BTW: the same code runs well on windows. (Of course diff URL is generated).

**Edit:** For URLs like:

```
private:factory/simpress
```

I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error message when the corresponding application (Calc, Writer etc.) is **not installed** in your system.

I originally tried to install the (Debian) metapackage `openoffice.org-headless` which did not contain any of the individual programs, only the core infrastructure.

Comment: FYI, I am getting this "URL seems to be an unsupported one" error for password protected docs.

Comment: This was super helpful.  Thanks, I tried to be clever too with the headless install.